# Pandas.query, defining a variable

Tags: python, pandas

In this example I want to select all values from the dataframe with a datevalue of more than 7440. Yet it doesn't work in the below code as I receive the "dv is not defined". So how do I define it in a pandas dataframe. Any help would be great.

```
dv = 7440
values = df.query('datevalue > dv' and country = "usa"')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `@` for variable and change `=` to double `==` for compare equality:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['usa','canada','slovakia','nepal'],
                   'datevalue':[7800,8440,10000,50000]})

print (df)
    country  datevalue
0       usa       7800
1    canada       8440
2  slovakia      10000
3     nepal      50000

dv = 7440
values = df.query('datevalue > @dv and country == "usa"')
print (values)
  country  datevalue
0     usa       7800
```

Comment: that was fast well done.

Comment: @MathiasRa - Yes, I use it more times, so remember it.